# Liquid Detection using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

Is there anyway to detect an irregularly shaped object, like liquids, in image processing? I'm particularly using OpenCV python.

Comment: Could you be more specific, perhaps even provide some sample images of the concrete objects/scenarios you want to analyze?

Comment: everything is possible in OpenCV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At an abstract level, it's impossible to detect liquids since liquids in general are reflexive, reflections mean the end of Image Processing